# Get values inside double curly braces with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

From this string:

```
dfasd {{test}} asdhfj {{te{st2}} asdfasd {{te}st3}}
```

I would like to get the following substrings:

```
test, te{st2, te}st3
```

In other words I want keep everything inside double curly braces **including single curly braces**.

I can't use this pattern:

```
{{(.*)}}
```

because it matches the whole thing between first {{ and last }}:

```
test}} asdhfj {{te{st2}} asdfasd {{te}st3
```

I managed to get the first two with this regex pattern:

```
{{([^}]*)}}
```

Is there any way to get all three using regex?

Comment: Try `{{(.*?)}}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `{{(.*?)}}`.

`.*?` means to do a lazy / non greedy search => as soon as }} matches, it will capture the found text and stop looking. Otherwise it will do a greedy search and therefore start with the first {{ and end with the very last }}.

Comment: `.*?` is **not** greedy. It's lazy: It'll stop as soon as it gets a chance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation. The pattern does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't that pretty, but it doesn't use RegEx and makes it clear what you are trying to accomplish.

```js
const testString = 'dfasd {{test}} asdhfj {{te{st2}} asdfasd {{te}st3}}';

const getInsideDoubleCurly = (str) => str.split('{{')
  .filter(val => val.includes('}}'))
  .map(val => val.substring(0, val.indexOf('}}')));

console.log(getInsideDoubleCurly(testString));
```